# Raw JavaScript to remove some spaces around an element

Tags: javascript, anchor, whitespace, space

Can anybody help with finding a raw JavaScript solution to remove some spaces around an anchor element.

I currently have the anchor nested in a table cell and there's an `&nbsp;` just before the anchor that causing the anchor (which I've styled to be a block element) to appear on the next line.

I'm pretty sure I know how to do it with jQuery but I wanted a raw JavaScript solution, can anybody help?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mhksG/).

Comment: That's not jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/trim. Even if you meant [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) you'd still need to do something with the returned string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code removes **&nbsp;** before anchor:

```
var s = document.getElementById('ttt').innerHTML;
s = s.replace(/&nbsp;[\s\r\n\t]*(<a)/gm, "$1");
document.getElementById('ttt').innerHTML = s;
```

"ttt" - your table id attribute.